# Missing membership roles on asp.net deployment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2003

I recently deployed an asp.net 3.5 project on a production server. It uses roles (.net membership). The website works (display pages and I can login).

Although the roles are in the database, they don't work on the production server.

I tried with this:

```
string[] roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
```

But it return an empty string.

Users and roles are related to the only row in the `aspnet_Applications` table

```
ApplicationName:/
LowerApplicationName:/
ApplicationId:5a354523-6cc2-40e7-be1e-d40f8e66a041
```

I thought that it did not work because I don't put `applicationName` property line in Web.config

```
<membership defaultProvider="WAESMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
  <clear />
  <add name="MyMembershipProvider" 
             applicationName="/"
  ...
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Still not working after adding the `applicationName` property

UPDATE

Combination of situations

I need to change my application name here:

[image]

Then, edit Web.xml as Muthu said.

Finally, I deleted and created again the membership tables with the new applicationName

Comment: did you enable the roleManager?

Comment: adding "/" means current application. so may be some other reason for problem. you enabled RoleManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be because

- You might not have copied/inserted the roles yet
- You have copied/added them when you had your application name as /, so you might have to change/update the application id of the roles to the new one or create the roles using new application name

  Also I see that you have not used the default Membership or role provider. If you do not use any custom provider, then stick to the default entries for providers (except changing application names)

  ```
  <membership>
    <providers>
     <clear/>
       <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
       enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
       maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
       applicationName="YourAppName" />
    </providers>
  </membership>

  <profile>
    <providers>
     <clear/>
     <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="YourAppName" />
    </providers>
   </profile>

  <roleManager enabled="false">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="YourAppName" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  ```

Comment: Muthu, when use autocomplete option on membership and profile block aplicationName property appears in a contextual menu, but it doesn't appear in roleManager block. What does it mean?

Comment: auto-complete is not be important and was never a reliable friend of mine. The simplest thing to do is to create a new Asp .net MVC 3 app in Visual Studio 2010 which will create a lot of these things by default for you except the application name part. Then you can compare this against your current config and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar issue. Please, check the following:

1. Are the roles created in the database connected to the production server?
2. If not, try using the Web Site Administration Tool in the production server in order to create the roles properly. This is a very good article about that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/03/09/how-to-use-web-site-administration-tool-without-installing-vs-2005.aspx.
3. When I have used the role managers I have had to re-create the schema in the database connected to the production server. In order to do this, you will need to make some changes to the machine.config. i.e.: adding the *autogenerateschema="true"* to your role provider, and increasing *trust level="Full"*.

I am not sure what your scenario is, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks aleafonso for your link, I was looking for a while

Comment: @aurahama happy to help. I would appreciate if you can upvote the answer then. Cheers

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that privilege for now